# Proving an Inequality with Algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

From my College Math Class:

Let $x < 2\sqrt{k}$. Prove using algebra that $x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} < 2\sqrt{k + 1}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: hint1: calculate $2\sqrt{k+1}-x>\cdots$ and multiply by conjugated quantity. hint2: $\sqrt{k}<\sqrt{k+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Using that $x<2\sqrt{k}$ we want to show that  $$x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2\sqrt{k+1}$$

Or $$2\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}+1<2(k+1)=2k+1+1$$

which follows by **AM-GM**  $$2\sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}\le2k+1$$

with never equality.

---

Or note that $$2\sqrt{k+1}-2\sqrt{k}=2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$